# Let $A$ be a ring. Let $x$ nilpotent and $u$ $\in$ unit of $A$ then $(x + u)$ $\in$ unity of $A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We have that, $x^{n}=0$ for some $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}_{+}^{*}$.

I want to find some $y$ $\in$ $A$, such that, $(x+u)y=1$, 
so that $(x+u)$ is unity of $A$.

Could you help me determine $y$ or show a better demonstration?

Comment: Hint: it suffices to show $1 + u^{-1}x$ is a unit. How might we compute $\frac{1}{1+a}$?

Comment: Is $A$ commutative?

Comment: Yes, A is commutative.